# How do you explore the reasons of losing traffic with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic, web-traffic

Let's say:

- you had 10k visitors per month on average in the year 2014,
- you have only 5k visitors per month on average in the year 2017

i.e. the traffic has suffered a -50%.

**What tools does Google Analytics offer to compare 2 years like this?**

Example of what I would be looking for:

1. Easy way to **get a table/list of referrals in year 2014 that are no more referrals in 2017, or referrals for which the % of total traffic has dropped between 2014 and 2017**
2. More generally than just `Referral` source of traffic, which other source of traffic has dropped significantly?

About 1., it's the kind of thing I would like to see in Analytics' `Analytics Intelligence` tool. Is it available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it.

1. First select a date range and a comparison date range:

   [image]
2. Then go to *Acquisition > Channels*.
3. Click on *Referral* (or another channel)
4. Choose *Sort Type: Absolute Change*, go to the bottom of page and choose *Show rows: 5000* (by the way if someone knows how to have *Show rows: 5000* by default, that would be useful)
5. Go to the bottom of the page: you'll see the highest losses of referral traffic:

   [image]